# In Google Apps Script, is there a way to define two versions of the logoUrl, one for dark mode and one for light?

Tags: google-apps-script, darkmode, graphical-logo, google-workspace-add-ons, lightmode

I'm using Apps Script to create an add-on for extending Gmail. I'm using a black & white icon and it looks great when the user's Gmail UI is in light mode, but becomes invisible in dark mode. Is there a way to use two different `logoUrl`'s, one for each UI mode? I haven't found any documentation or example that points to a solution. The Gmail section of my manifest `appsscript.json` is:

```
  "gmail": {
    "name": "MailReceipts",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/receipt_long_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "getContextualAddOn"
      }
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#3d8c5b",
    "secondaryColor": "#54bf7d"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no parameter that lets you define two versions of the `logoUrl` in Google Workspace Add-Ons manifest JSON. The only available [JSON field](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#common) under the `common` parameter is as follows:

```
{
  "homepageTrigger": {
    object (HomepageTrigger)
  },
  "layoutProperties": {
    object (LayoutProperties)
  },
  "logoUrl": string,
  "name": string,
  "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
    string
  ],
  "universalActions": [
    {
      object (UniversalAction)
    }
  ],
  "useLocaleFromApp": boolean
}
```

[layoutProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#layoutproperties) field only controls the Google Workspace add-on toolbar and button colors and appearance not the logo color itself

### Suggestion:

A workaround would be to choose an image or logo that is visible for both light and dark mode. You can easily change the logo by replacing the image url in `logoUrl` field.

### References:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#addons

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/gmail-addons

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#common

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#layoutproperties

Comment: I suspected as much, Thanks George.

Comment: Welcome Carmen, glad I could be of help.